# If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint events, then $P(A\mid B)$ is?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

If $A$ and $B$ are two disjoint events, then would $P(A\mid B)$ equal 0 or would it just equal $P(A)$ considering $P(B)$ doesn't effect it?

Comment: If the events are disjoint then knowing $B$ occurred means that you know that $A$ did not occur.  Hence the answer is indeed $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb{P}(A\mid B)=\dfrac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)}=0$ because $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)=\mathbb{P}(\varnothing)=0$.

Intuitively, because $A$ and $B$ do not occur together, given that we know $B$ has occurred, we know for sure that $A$ has not occurred. So the conditional probability of $A$ given $B$ should be $0$.

Comment: makes sense thank you!

Comment: there is a way to formalize this intuition when $P(B)=0$?

Answer (score 0):

If they are disjoint, then $P(A|B)=\dfrac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=0$, because $P(A\cap B)=0$.

Comment: this doesn't hold if $P(B)=0$

Comment: @Schach21 makes sense thank you!

Comment: @Masacroso Good point. How would you go about that? Because $P(A|B)=0$ must hold regardless of $P(B)$, if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

Comment: @Schach21 I dont know... it is a very interesting question. As far as I know there is no strategy or theory to show what happen when we condition in a event of probability zero, the case for events of probability zero generated by random variables is other story

Comment: @Masacroso for when $P(B)=0$ that formula breaks. Then you have to use the actual definition of conditional probability, namely $P(F|\mathcal{G})=E[I_F|\mathcal{G}]$, where the conditional expectation is the usual integral involving $\sigma$-algebras and the random variables. That, of course, is out of the scope of this discussion. But as expected, the general theory is robust :)